# Register javascript globally without placing in .aspx page in asp.net

Tags: javascript

I have a big project in asp.net, Some pages having different master pages and many pages don't have any master page. In short, there is no common layout available in my project. Now, I need to integrate session idle timeout functionality in whole project and I have to register my javascript in each and every page.

So, is there anyway to register javascript globally through code, like in global.ashx file and trigger javascript function?

Thanks
Imrnakhan

Answer (score 0):

you can create default layout which will be used in every page. incase you have a page with existing layout then in master layout will be using default layout page. so hierarchy will be like

---

Default Layout: This will have javascript call

---

New Page without layout :
Default layout + partial page

---

New master Layout :
Master layout page With default layout

---

New page with layout:
New master layout + page